# How to find a match in different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, compare, match

I have two tables. The first one is 'volvo_skus' which contains only one column with SKU's (30k rows)
and the second one is named 'truckparts'.

The second one has all the data. It has 15 columns with different info for the product like Category, Parts_info, OE_NUMBER and etc and its nearly 800k rows.

The thing I'm trying to do is: if the SKU in the table volvo_skus matches with the OE_NUMBER in the table truckparts, select and apply all the info for that SKU from the table 'truckparts'. The same principle as VLOOKUP in excel.

I tried to do something like this, but failed.

```
select *
from
    truckparts002 A
inner join volvo_skus B
    on A.OE_NUMBER = B.SKU
```

SAMPLE:

volvo_skus table

```
-------------
|    SKU    |
|  205888   |
|  205890   |
|  205892   |
|  205894   |
|  205893   |
|  205899   |
-------------
```

truckparts table (800k rows approximately)

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | CAR_BRAND  |  CAR_MODEL | CAR_BODY | CAR_KW | CAR_CC | OE_NUMBER | CATEGORY | PARTS_INFO |
   VOLVO        FM 12       Platform   279      12100    205888      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x21
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   281      12100    205890      Heating    Dimensions 380x180x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   278      12100    205892      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   270      12100    205894      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   275      12100    205893      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   279      12100    205895      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   279      12100    205896      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   279      12100    205897      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   279      12100    205898      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
   VOLVO    FM 12       Platform   280      12100    205899      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
```

The output I want:

Third table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SKU   | CAR_BRAND  |  CAR_MODEL | CAR_BODY | CAR_KW | CAR_CC | CATEGORY | PARTS_INFO |
 205888   VOLVO        FM 12       Platform   279      12100      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x21
 205890   VOLVO        FM 12       Platform   281      12100      Heating    Dimensions 380x180x20
 205892   VOLVO        FM 12       Platform   278      12100      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
 205894   VOLVO        FM 12       Platform   270      12100      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
 205893   VOLVO        FM 12       Platform   275      12100      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
 205899   VOLVO        FM 12       Platform   280      12100      Heating    Dimensions 380x190x20
```

Comment: Seeems like a strange design to have a separate table for Volvo SKU's. Do you have another table for Scania SKU's? Normally you have one, common table for all SKU's.

Comment: Also, A and B are poor table aliases. Chose aliases that make sense, like `tp` for truckparts.

Comment: I got both files with the data from different sources.
volvo skus are from our supplier
and the second table 'truckparts' was bought from a programmer.
OE_NUMBER and SKU is basically the same code. But I need all the data only for the supplier file (volvo_skus table). I don't need the whole 800k rows. It's like I want to filter the data only for the SKUS from the table volvo_skus

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Added the sample

Comment: I managed, using your table templates, to get the expected output using a Inner Join. Are you sure you are using a Inner Join correctly? There are some good examples at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Did you use the same query that I wrote?

Comment: When I run this query, the CPU goes crazy, like 100% forever. Maybe its because the data cpu needs to calculate is very big?